# Redirecionar para outra Página Com javaScript de uma forma suave (slide, fade in , etc)

Tags: javascript, html, css, funções, transição

Galera aqui a baixo está meu codigo.
acontece o seguinte,
eu estou usando uma função java que ele redireciona automaticamente o usuário para outra pagina.
acontece que queria que ao direcionar o usuário, a transição de paginas fosse com fade ou algo suave.
o link do site abaixo está no ar , caso alguém queira entrar pra dar uma olhada fica mais fácil entender.

https://dannslima.github.io/danilovasconcelos/

" A PRIMEIRA PÁGINA É PRETA, A SEGUNDA PÁGINA É BRANCA
SE EU CONSEGUIR APLICAR UMA TRANSIÇÃO SUAVE VAI FICAR COMO SE FOSSE UMA PAGINA POR TRAZ APARECENDO LENTAMENTE "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script>

    function redirecionar() {
        window.location.href = "/index.html";
        document.getElementById("fundo").style.background = "red";

    };
    setTimeout(redirecionar, 3000);

</script>

<body id="fundo">
    <h1 style="font-size: 3em ; color: white ; text-align: center">DANILO VASCONCELOS</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Como assim jovem, não deu para entender muito bem o que vc quer... tem algum exemplo, ou consegue explicar melhor sua ideia?

Comment: claro.. olha esse site http://wp.regaltheme.com/mim/#service
estou fazendo um do zero imitando o layout..

a primeira tela é preta com o titulo "me"..
depois há uma leve transição para a tela principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara isso é uma animação de *fade* quando entra na página, tanto que se vc entrar lá e ficar apertando `f5` a animação fica recarregando etc..

Não é algo difícil de se fazer, basta vc ter um elemento com `position:fixed` e que cobre toda a tela e com um `animation` para fazer o fade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para colocar o texto no centro da tela eu usei `flexbox` no *container* pai e um *pseudo elemento* `::after` na `div.mim` e coloquei o texto no `.mim::after { content: "MIM" }`

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mim {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
   user-select: none;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 1000ms linear forwards;
}
.mim::after {
  content: "MIM"; /* texto MIM que está no centro da tela */
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    z-index: -10;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: -10;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mim"></div><!-- div que vai cobrir tudo e tem o efeito de fade -->

<h1>meu h1</h1>
<h3>meu h3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis aperiam et numquam ea. Expedita eos qui consequuntur debitis rem sunt alias dolor necessitatibus. Accusantium pariatur veritatis fuga distinctio laborum porro.</p>

<img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100">

<form action="">
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  <button>btn</button>
</form>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Se quiser fazer com jQuery é só fazer um `fadeOut()` no elemento. Repare que agora não é uma animação com CSS e sim o jQuery que faz o *fade* na `div.mim`. Documentação oficial do jQuery sobre isso: https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

**Veja o resultado no código abaixo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mim").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mim {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 10;
}

.mim::after {
    content: "MIM";
    /* texto MIM que está no centro da tela */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="mim"></div><!-- div que vai cobrir tudo e tem o efeito de fade -->

<h1>meu h1</h1>
<h3>meu h3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis aperiam et numquam ea. Expedita eos qui consequuntur debitis rem sunt alias dolor necessitatibus. Accusantium pariatur veritatis fuga distinctio laborum porro.</p>

<img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100">

<form action="">
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <button>btn</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ola, deu certinho.
usei a primeira opção pois nao manjo de jquery.

mt top. irei estudar mais sobre a propriedade after"